# oracle sql query for records with timestamp that falls between two timestamps

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I have two timestamps in String format `2015-05-06T15:39:00` and `2015-04-06T15:39:00`.

What is the sql query for Oracle that I can query all the records in the table that has timestamp that falls within this range.

Comment: Convert a string dateTime `2015-05-06T15:39:00` and `2015-04-06T15:39:00` to a timestamp format which can be used to query for records that falls within this range using sql in oracle db?

Answer (score 25):

And with alternative way you can use between

```
SELECT *
FROM tab1
WHERE timestamps BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2015-05-06T15:39:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('2015-04-06T15:39:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS');
```

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE timestamps >= TO_DATE('2015-05-06T15:39:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
AND timestamps <= TO_DATE('2015-04-06T15:39:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: doesn't work. First, the timestamp must be surrounded by ' '. Secondly, it shows the error, not a valid month.

Comment: In question there is not timezone, ie. `Z` at the end

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers worked for me.

however, First simply replace 'T' you have with a ' '(space) and use below query which worked for me

```
    select * from tb1 
    where timestamps BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2015-05-06 15:39:00', 'YYYY-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') 
                          AND TO_DATE('2015-04-06 15:39:00', 'YYYY-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the literal into DATE using **TO_DATE** and required **format mask** to compare the timestamp column with the input **timestamp** values.

**Setup**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(A TIMESTAMP);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t(A) VALUES(to_date('2015-04-10T15:39:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'));

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(A) VALUES(to_date('2015-05-01T15:39:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'));

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(A) VALUES(to_date('2015-03-01T15:39:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'));

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

A
----------------------------
10-APR-15 03.39.00.000000 PM
01-MAY-15 03.39.00.000000 PM
01-MAR-15 03.39.00.000000 PM
```

**Query**

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2    FROM t
  3   WHERE A BETWEEN
  4            to_date('2015-04-06T15:39:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
  5           AND
  6             to_date('2015-05-06T15:39:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS');

A
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
10-APR-15 03.39.00.000000 PM
01-MAY-15 03.39.00.000000 PM
```

So, I got the required rows as my desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The below one is for timestamp and you can change for your required time

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1 
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN to_date('21/11/2017 23:59:59','dd/MM/rrrr hh24:mi:ss')            
  AND to_date('21/12/2017 15:59:59','dd/MM/rrrr hh24:mi:ss');`
```