# Identifying events that have happened between two times in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to calculate the number of events that have happened between 09:00AM and 10:00AM however instead of bring back all events that have happened between those hours I am only returning the events that have happened at 10:00, i'm new to sql so this seems like it should be an easy query but I've been struggling for hours. My query looks as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM EVENTS
WHERE TIME BETWEEN '09:00:00AM' AND '10:00:00AM';
```

I know that there are 30+ events to occur between those two times (because I counted them manually) but for some reason this query only brings back the ones to happen at 10:00:00AM exactly, please help.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070691/oracle-sql-query-for-records-with-timestamp-that-falls-between-two-timestamps

Comment: What data type is your TIME column?