# how to check Date is between 2 dates in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

i want retrieve rows based on Date that within  2 dates or
   it will be greater than   date or  less than date

```
where id =5 
 AND ( :fromDate is  null or  trunc ( :fromDate ) >= trun(TABLE.DEPOSIT_DATE ))
 AND ( :toDate is  null or    trunc ( :toDate )<= trunc (TABLE.DEPOSIT_DATE ))
```

when i pass paramters to :fromDate and :ToDate at this format (7/25/2018 1:21:55 PM) for example

the query return 0 rows

Comment: Pass the parameters in as dates, not strings.

Comment: i have passed them as Date and choosed from Date Picker in Toad for oracle

Comment: `the query return 0 rows` <= The reason for that most likely is that there are 0 rows that match that condition. Keep in mind you also posted `id=5`, that could limit the results as well.

Comment: See answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070691/oracle-sql-query-for-records-with-timestamp-that-falls-between-two-timestamps by Moudiz

Comment: no , i'm sure that i have data between the 2 dates i choose

Answer (score 0):

Try using "BETWEEN" operator as below example

```
SELECT * FROM employee where joining_date BETWEEN '2006-02-14 04:34:33' AND '2016-02-15 04:34:12';
```

Comment: i cant use between because i may use fromdate or todate

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server 
then first set the date format 
like : - set daqteformat dmy 
and date condition u can use between 
like : Entrydate between '01/01/2018' and '31/01/2018'

Comment: im using oracle

Answer (score 0):

Why you cannot use between ?  check below example using plsql block statement to use bind variable the same as your example

```
SET serveroutput ON size 2000
/
declare
  T_DATE date;
  F_DATE DATE;
  C_ID   number(2);
begin
  T_DATE := to_date('01/07/2018','dd/mm/yyyy');
  F_DATE := to_date('01/06/2018','dd/mm/yyyy');

  delete from  ex_employee;

  insert into ex_employee (id, X_NAME, T_ADDED) values (1, 'aa', sysdate);
  insert into ex_employee
    (id, X_NAME, T_ADDED)
  values
    (2, 'bb', sysdate - 1);
  insert into ex_employee
    (id, X_NAME, T_ADDED)
  values
    (3, 'cc', to_date('20/06/2018','dd/mm/yyyy'));
  commit;

  select id
    into C_ID
    from ex_employee
      where T_ADDED between F_DATE and T_DATE or F_DATE is null or T_DATE is null;
dbms_output.put_line(c_id);
end;
/




PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
  3
```